# CANbus data sample

Tags: data-request, computing

I am looking for a sample of a raw CANbus hex data file

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller_area_network

I have had no luck searching. 
Anyone have any ideas/links/help?

Edit:
I have been doing more research. The standard for the data frames in communication only get turned into files when there is something to intercept and store the messages. There are boxes which send this wirelessly to servers.

I am wondering if it is an interceptor specific file format?

Comment: Did you ever find any?

Comment: Did you find sample data? I am also looking for the same.